# RichTextBox doesn't appear when content is exported as Image

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a Panel where the contents are added dynamically and exported as an image file. I export the content as image using the following code below.

```
 Bitmap tempBmp = new Bitmap(pnlCanvas.Width, pnlCanvas.Height);
 pnlCanvas.DrawToBitmap(tempBmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, pnlCanvas.Width, pnlCanvas.Height));
 tempBmp.Save(fileName);
```

In a particular case i have a RichTextBox control added to the panel. I found that the control is not seen when exported.

I am not sure what goes wrong. Please guide me what should be done.

Thanks in Advance,
K

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is stated [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap.aspx) DrawToBitmap doesn't work with `RichTextBox`. Try painting the content using *GDI+* manually.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the control is actually there, is it disposed or just invisible. Try adding some value to it and check if it returns the value with variable or gives you error (if it's gone). That's my ideas :)

Comment: Yes the controls exist and i am able to do the modifications to the same. But when i export it as an image file i just see only the outline of the RichTextBox control and not the content inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Just succeeded with exactly what i was looking for. I am answering my own question so that it could help someone looking for the same.

Sample code to capture the ActiveX controls and Export as Image.

```
Rectangle ctrlRect = myControl.RectangleToScreen(myControl.ClientRectangle);
Bitmap myImage = new Bitmap(ctrlRect.Width,ctrlRect.Height,PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
Graphics myGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(myImage);
myGraphics.CopyFromScreen(ctrlRect.Location, Point.Empty, myControl.Size);
myImage.Save("sample.png");
```